# Select specific fields and write them to a new file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I've been task with kind of summarising a few files into a tsv file. I have to select specific data from a list of files and write it as a line of tab-seperated columns in a tsv file. Every line in the files have a 'name' as a first column so it is easy to filter data ($1 == "NAME"). One file == one line in tsv. So far I wrote this:

```
#! /bin/bash
cat > newFile.txt
for f in *.pdb; do
awk '$1 == "ACCESSION" {print $2}' ORS="/t" "$f" >> newFile.txt
awk '$1 == "DEFINITION" {print $2}' ORS="/t" "$f" >> newFile.txt
awk '$1 == "SOURCE" {print $2}' ORS="/t" "$f" >> newFile.txt
awk '$1 == "LOCUS" {print$4}' ORS="/r" "$f" >> newFile.txt
done
```

Obviously this attrocity of a code does not work. Is it possible to modify what I wrote and complete the task using awk?

Example of a file:

```
LOCUS \t NM_123456 \t 2000bp \t mRNA
DEFINITION \t Very nice gene from a very nice mouse
ACCESSION \t NM_123456
VERSION \t 1.000
SOURCE \t Very nice mouse
```

end result:

```
NM_123456 /t Very nice gene from a very nice mouse /t Very nice mouse /t mRNA
NM_345678 /t Not so nice gene from an angry elephant /t Angry Elephant /t mRNA
```

"/t" stands for a tab (I did not know how to write it down sorry). Also the example files contain much more information, I just gave a 'header' let's say.

Comment: Can you provide sample file(s) and expected output?

Comment: And please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69881942/edit) your question with the sample, don't add it in the comments :)

Comment: Hey. I have modified the question as you asked. I hope it's clear enough ^^

Comment: Grat ! Could you tell us if a single file can have only 1 field of the same name ? (i.e., only one ACCESSION / DEFINITION / LOCUS / VERSION / SOURCE)

Comment: Yes, the field names are unique!

Comment: Which is correct of `ASCESSION` or `ACCESSION`?

Comment: ah sorry my mistake it's ACCESSION

Comment: It sounds from the text like you have multiple input files but you only provided 1 input file in your example. Whenever you have multiple of anything to deal with make sure to provide at least 2 of those somethings in your example as solutions that handle 1 thing are often quite different from those that handle multiple and calling the 1-thing solution multiple times is usually a bad approach. It's also not clear how you'd get the output you posted from the input you posted - where did "NM_345678 " appear from, for example?

Comment: As you can see by looking at the answers, some assume that the order of the various lines is always the same, others don't. Please add this information to your question (not in a comment). Also, some answers will not work as expected if lines are missing. So, do the files always contain all lines? Please also clarify this in your question.

Comment: Also, some of us are assuming your files don't **really** have blanks on either side of every tab. If we're correct about that then please remove those blanks from your example. Also the representation for a tab is `\t`, not `/t`.

Answer (score 2):

In plain bash:

```
for file in *.pdb; do
    acc=
    def=
    src=
    loc=
    while IFS=$'\t' read -ra fields; do
        if [[ ${fields[0]} = "ACCESSION" ]]; then
            acc=${fields[1]}
        elif [[ ${fields[0]} = "DEFINITION" ]]; then
            def=${fields[1]}
        elif [[ ${fields[0]} = "SOURCE" ]]; then
            src=${fields[1]}
        elif [[ ${fields[0]} = "LOCUS" ]]; then
            loc=${fields[3]}
        fi
    done < "$file"
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$acc" "$def" "$src" "$loc" >> newFile.txt
done
```

Comment: Hmm I see what you did, thanks! Could you explain a little why can I not use 'awk' and why my code is rubbish?

Comment: @PetrasNasvytis You can use awk, of course. But calling awk inside a shell loop is not recommended. You could accomplish this task entirely in awk. I did it in bash because there is no awk tag in the question.

Comment: Ah I see I see. Still not entirely sure how this all work :D That's the first question I post. I will keep your comment in mind :) Thanks

Comment: @M.NejatAydin you're correct that calling awk inside a shell loop is not recommended but the solution is to get rid of the shell loop, not to get rid of awk. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

If every file has those lines in *same order in every file*, and they appear *exactly once per file* (no more, no less), you can do this:

```
awk '
$1 == "ASCESSION" {printf "%s\t", $2}
$1 == "DEFINITION" {printf "%s\t", $2}
$1 == "SOURCE" {printf "%s\t", $2}
$1 == "LOCUS" {print $4}' *.pdb > table.tsv
```

However, if the order of lines varies, or some files don't have every line, or some files have multiple lines the same (eg `SOURCE foo` appears twice), you will need something more complex, like this:

```
awk '
function print_row(cols) {
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf "%s\t", cols[i]
        cols[i] = ""
    }
    print cols[3]
    cols[3] = ""
}

NR!=FNR && FNR==1 {print_row(cols)}

$1 == "ASCESSION" {cols[0] = $2}
$1 == "DEFINITION" {cols[1] = $2}
$1 == "SOURCE" {cols[2] = $2}
$1 == "LOCUS" {cols[3] = $4}

END {print_row(cols)}' *.pdb > table.tsv
```

It always prints a neat table, with columns lining up correctly, regardless of the order of lines in a file, and even if some lines are missing or occur more than once. If a line occurs more than once, the last occurrence is used.

Answer (score 1):

If `gawk`, which supports `ENDFILE` block, is available, please try:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '                # assign input/output field separator to a tab character
BEGIN {
    split("ACCESSION,DEFINITION,SOURCE,LOCUS", names, ",")
                                        # assign an array "names" to the list of names
}
{
    if ($1 == "LOCUS") a[$1] = $4
    else a[$1] = $2
}
ENDFILE {                               # this block is invoked after reading each file
    print a[names[1]], a[names[2]], a[names[3]], a[names[4]]
                                        # print a["ACCESSION"], a["DEFINITION"], .. in order as a tsv
    delete a                            # clear array "a"
}' *.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box (untested):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ f[$1] = ($1 == "LOCUS" ? $4 : $2) }
$1 == "SOURCE" {
    print f["ACCESSION"], f["DEFINITION"], f["SOURCE"], f["LOCUS"]
}
' *.pdb > newFile.txt
```

The above assumes every input file has the same tag-value pairs as shown in  the input file in your question and that SOURCE is always the last one.